# Sandboxing destroyes my application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, sandbox

I just tried to sandbox my lion application using Xcode. However, when I try to launch my application the app crashes immediately. There's no error code or gdb output.
Do you have a tip for me how to solve this problem? How do I figure out what is causing my app to crash?

Comment: Do you need your application to be sandboxed?

Answer (score 2):

Try removing any keys in your `Entitlements` file that have to do with iCloud (`ubiquity`)

Comment: It worked for me. Also take at look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017839/issues-with-ubiquity-container-entitlements-and-code-signing-not-playing-nice